# Where to get school district boundaries?

Tags: data-request, usa, education

[Census.gov](http://www.census.gov) usually makes available the shapefiles containing school district boundaries. Due to the US government shutdown, [census.gov](http://www.census.gov) is down. Does anyone know where to download a recently archived copy?

Comment: This question refers to a temporary situation that has passed. Should we remove the question? Or rewrite it to answer it for the general case of when Census.gov is not shut down?

Answer (score 7):

1) [google](https://www.google.com) to find the exact website of the [census.gov](http://census.gov) that contains the information you're looking for.  [google](https://www.google.com)'s search results still contains all of the shuttered web pages

2) paste that url into the "[wayback machine](http://archive.org)"

3) choose the most recent blue circle that's pre-shutdown

Example: [Here is the US Census 2017 School District TIGERLine/Shapefile Web Interface saved via Wayback Machine](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2017&layergroup=School+Districts).

Note: the Census' FTP server will not save in the Wayback Machine; In very recent past, the team behind the Wayback Machine had started bypassing US .gov server restrictions in order to preserve sites/data, but for reasons unknown, Wayback is still blocked by Census FTP.